low-budget movie about ex-con who kidnaps a dancer
Ex-con was actually innocent of charges he was doing time for.  Kidnaps a dancer...tap dancer or ballroom dancer.  She is a willing kidnap victim and I believe they go to visit her family and pose as a married couple.  It has been a good 10-15 years since I saw this, probably made in mid 90's. My sister and I were discussing it lastnight trying to think of any actors in the movie, I cannot remember anyone in it.  English speaking, pretty sure that it is an indie film.

Sounds like Vincent Gallo's Buffalo '66 from 1998.

Having just served five years in prison for a crime he did not commit, Billy Brown (Vincent Gallo) kidnaps a young tap dancer named Layla (Christina Ricci) and forces her to pretend to be his wife. Layla allows herself to be kidnapped and it is clear she is romantically attracted to Billy from the start, but Billy all the while is compelled to deal with his own demons, his loneliness and his depression.

Here's the trailer:




The greatest use of a Yes song in a movie, EVER.
